# Where to add animation properties - jQuery CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Where in this function do I add the animation properties to the adding and removing of additional styles?

```
$('#close').click(function () {
    $('img').removeClass('additionalStyle');
    $(".theDiv").removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/a2txcLou/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, the css will be a little bit long because of all the vendor prefix:

https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/a2txcLou/6/

```
 <a href="#" class="trigger">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100">    
    </a>    


    <a href="#" class="trigger">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100">    
    </a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
        $('img').removeClass('fadein-translate');
        $(this).addClass('fadeout-translate');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fadein-translate {
    -moz-animation: fadein-translate 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: fadein-translate 3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fadein-translate 3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadein-translate 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
        -o-transform: translateY(50px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
        -o-transform: translateY(50px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
        -o-transform: translateY(50px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadeout-translate {
    -moz-animation: fadeout-translate 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: fadeout-translate 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fadeout-translate 1.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeout-translate 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
        -o-transform: translateY(30px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeout-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
        -o-transform: translateY(30px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout-translate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
        -o-transform: translateY(30px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/a2txcLou/6/

Comment: That's beautiful and really close to what I need. Can you help me to concatenate this? Clicking on image 2 restores visibility of image 1

Comment: Bingo. You're a gentleman and a scholar, Leo. I'd buy you a beer if I could. You've no idea how much you've helped me today. I learned a lot too. Thanks a million. (This really has been the nicest stackoverflow thread I've ever had)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $('img').fadeOut(function() {
        $('img').addClass('visible').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

See the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/a2txcLou/3/

Comment: That might just do it, but the function needs to remove the additional style from the previous selection whilst adding additional styles to the current selection. Are you willing to help me a little further? I'm currently not so great and concatonating my functions and i want to keep it as d.r.y as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script using `animate` function and `transition` CSS attribute 
CSS

```
img.visible {
    border: 50px solid black;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   $('.trigger').click(function () {
       var handler=$(this);
       if($('img.visible').length>0){  
         $('img.visible').animate({borderWidth:0},500,function(){
           $(this).removeClass("visible").prop("style","");
           handler.children("img").addClass("visible");
        });
      }else{
        handler.children("img").addClass("visible");
      }                  
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2txcLou/9/